# Powerpoint 2016 - Default Template on the Backstage

Tags: powerpoint, default, powerpoint-2016

In PPT 2013, there was an option to save a template file `blank.potx` in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates` so it would appear on the Backstage as a "Default Theme". That also allowed to use `CTRL + N` to create a new presentation using the template. [More detailed info.](http://echosvoice.com/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-powerpoint-2013/)

Starting from the PPT 2016, a new location for the templates was defined `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Custom Office Templates`.
I guess, that lead to some inconveniences, which resulted in making [this support entry](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Where-are-my-custom-templates-88ed77ca-df34-49e9-9087-3f01ae296e6e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), explaining the new location.

The problem is, I want to be able to use `CTRL + N` and also see `blank.potx` named as "Default Template" or so. The way I found so far is to "trick" by placing `blank.potx` in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates` and copy-paste the renamed version of the same file in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Custom Office Templates`. Unfortunately, it does not appear as the first choice, and may mislead due to name inconsistency. Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that only after you save your first template (format potx), two new links will appear under the "search for templates" widget:

[*FEATURED* and *PERSONAL* template links as shown in the "New" dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1627.jpg)

The *PERSONAL* link will show all template files in the default templates directory: %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Custom Office Templates

If you add a folder there (or a shortcut to your personal templates folder), all templates will be easily accessible